# access properties of the selectedItem xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

Trying to access the property{Name} inside a list , using slectedItem ex.

```
 var SName = e.SelectedItem;

            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            await DisplayAlert("Item Selected", SName.ToString(), "Ok");
```

the common way will be just   **var SName = e.SelectedItem.Name;**. However I dont get the option to access it . 
I already have the get;set; and if I add a breakpoint on the mention line it shows me the Name property and value that I want to display. 
any suggestion ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.SelectedItem` is of type `object` - you need to cast it to the appropriate type first

```
var item = (MyType) e.SelectedItem;
var name = item.Name;
```

Comment: so, I tried .. var feedbackName = (feedback)e.SelectedItem;. it is strange because when I put the breakpoint there it shows me the property Name and its value . Then , I tried this . but give me error ** var name =feedback.Name;***

Comment: feedbackName.Name

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

You can use the type-testing operators to make it look cleaner. (C# 7.0+)

```cs
if(e.SelectedItem is MyType item)
{
  var name = item.Name;
  await DisplayAlert("Item Selected", name, "Ok");
}
return;
```